# Automatic gain control circuit with dc offset

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, gain

I have a circuit that takes a sine wave amplifies it a little bit but also adds a DC offset of 1.5V. It works perfectly no matter the input volume. Now that I am reworking everything it would be nice to be able to add an AGC circuit as well so no matter what input device the audio is from, the output will always be the same. Here is my current circuit:
[image: circuit schematic]
It uses OPA197's as the op-amps.
To add an AGC circuit to this I think there is a lot of ways to do it. Probably the best one is to just have a normal AGC circuit and amplifier first, and then use an op-amp or even just a voltage divider to add a DC offset.
The issue I have is how to make an AGC circuit. There are many schematics online but I find there's 2 main issues with them. They usually don't provide equations to work out the values of the components or they use a dual supply, which I'm not using in my circuit.
This is one I found and it's nice and simple:

[image: agc circuit]

But if you go to the actual [site](http://electriciantraining.tpub.com/14189/css/Automatic-Gain-Volume-Control-Agc-Avc-52.htm) then there doesn't seem to be any equations there. Or much at all to be honest.
The way I would like it to work would be that no matter where the audio is coming from (a phone on lowest volume or a computer on highest volume) the output of the circuit will always be constant. This would make my life much easier on later parts.

Could anyone give some insight on how to do this?

Edit for clarification:
The ADC on my microcontoller does not support negative voltages therefore the input signal must have a DC offset. It can also take voltages between 0 and 3.3 which is why I offset the signal at 1.5 so it can swing between 0 and 3.3.
I then feed this singal into my microcontroller to control some LED strips.
On the schematic R13 is the gain. The higher the value, the more gain there is. That sort of gives me 2 options:

- I can set the gain really high which will allow me to use my phone to provide audio without it being too quiet. This has 2 main issues. The extra gain will induce more noise and also if I want to use my computer to provide audio, I will get major clipping since the output amplitude of the computer is much higher.
- Or I can set the gain quite low allowing me to use my computer to provide audio without clipping. The issue with that is that that means the signal from my phone will be too weak to really make any difference to the output signal so it will just get picked up as "noise" in the software. 
  My idea for the AGC was to allow me to use any source for audio without any difference in the output amplitude but as pointed out that will mean quiet parts of the song become loud.

Second edit: Let me expand. It takes the adjusted signal and rather than that being fed (I should have mentioned this before i just totally forgot so my bad), the signals are fed into 4 more circuits. A negative and positive peak detector and a high and low pass filter (I am think about changing some of these). The lighting effect I am going for is from this video:
[example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU1GVVU9gLU)
My version is just basically more of a refined version of his. He has two inputs whereas I have 4 and I intend to use them for speed, brightness and colour. I understand the way I have it now is over-complicated however I know it works. It's not expensive either.
As for sound quality. You're right. Quality isn't an issue but obviously noise is. The good thing about this circuit is the fact that, as I said, I know it works and also the noise is determined by the op-amp choice. Also, although it's not an issue, using op-amps wont hurt the quality of the signal.
Originally my question was about an AGC circuit. Finding out that that won't work is fine.
To give a solid question then: is there anything I can do about a difference in input amplitude (so again, a phone will be quieter than a computer. Is there much I can do about this?). Improvements like this will make my coding job a bit easier since I don't have to try and implement some sort of "sensitivity" feature to adjust the sensitivity of the lights depending on the input.
Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the help a lot, but I'm not looking to know how to change my circuit. I created a post elsewhere months ago and I have a massive backlog of things I could try, including the one you suggested.

It's a bit of stretch but could something like [this](https://www.elecrow.com/download/X9C103S_Datasheet.pdf) be used? It's a digitally controlled potentiometer. Could I in theory use it in place of R13 and then use software to control the sensitivity by automatically adjusting the value of R13?

Comment: That isn't an AGC circuit - it's just a weakly designed single transistor amplifier with a volume control. Why do you require two unit gain inverting amplifiers to add some DC offset when it doesn't need anything like that.

Comment: "*... so no matter what input device the audio is from, the output will always be the same.*" That would be considered a problem by some. For one it will bring up all the quiet passages of music so that everything plays at the same volume. The second problem is that it will bring up all the noise in quiet and silent passages as the AGC raises the gain. As Andy says, that's not an AGC circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka It doesn't require it, that was just how it was designed. It takes in an audio signal applies an offset and amplifies it a bit. The output signal is inverted so then it's run through basically the same circuit to invert it again so it's back the same way as it's coming in.

Comment: @Transistor That's true, I didn't think about that. I realise noise would be an issue. In that case I will probably have to do it in software rather than in hardware.

Comment: You'll have similar noise problems if you're feeding low-level signals into an ADC set to accept high volume signals. What's the real problem you're trying to solve? [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: @Transistor I've added the edit for extra info.

Comment: That changes the question an awful lot. (1) You are not amplifying "a sine wave". You are processing an audio music signal which will be far more complex. (2) You are using the microcontroller to control lighting so you are making a sound-to-light converter or "colour-organ". This means that you don't care at all about sound quality, you don't need the DC offset because you can just half-wave rectify the signal. I think you need to improve your question to explain what the real problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: @Transistor. Another expansion has been made. It seems that long comment chains are not advised which is fair enough, and wants it to to be moved to a chat. Is that a good idea?